# howto connect dreamweaver with vsts

Tags: git, azure-devops, dreamweaver

We are using VSTS for many c# projects. All goes well. Now we want to add the sources of our webdesigner too to a repo in VSTS. His tool of choice for designing the sites is Dreamweaver.

We've set up a git connection to VSTS via console and all works fine. 
We installed the plugin described here :
https://helpx.adobe.com/dreamweaver/using/git-support.html

We can see the repo, see the states of files, but as soon as we want to push/pull using the dreamweaver plugin it fails. It seems that the way dreamweaver is performing the authentication is not the VSTS way.

Any suggestions ?

Comment: Do you solve this issue with my solution?

Comment: Not yet feedback from user.

Comment: How do you specify the credential? Provide the detail steps here.

Answer (score 1):

Try to use Alternate authentication credentials instead.

Go to `https://{your account}.visualstudio.com/_details/security/altcreds` and click Enable alternate authentication credentials option.

You also can use [Personal Access Token](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/vsts/git/_shared/personal-access-tokens) as password, username can be anything, such as test.